# unable to connect to localhost in IIS7 on Windows server 2003 R2?

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2003

I am trying to connect to localhost in IIS7  on Windows server 2003 R2
but this error coming all the time can you please give me a solution 
Please check this :

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately I had to format Windows server 2003 R2 and replace it with Windows server 2008 R2 , and now it's working very well.